# Bluetooth Device not connecting on Android app despite trying tutorials

Tags: android, exception, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, crash

I don't know what's wrong with it, but my app is searching for nearby Bluetooth devices, but the moment I'm trying to connect to one of these Bluetooth devices, the app crashes.

Please have a look

This is my **SearchBTDevice.java**. This is the activity that calls the ConnectBTDevice activity

```
package vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Set;

public class SearchBTDevice extends AppCompatActivity {

    public BluetoothAdapter BlueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    public ArrayAdapter PairedArrayAdapter;
    public ArrayAdapter BTArrayAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice btd;

    public ListView devicesFound;


    private final BroadcastReceiver BTReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver(){

       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
       {
           String action = intent.getAction();

           if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                   btd = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                   BTArrayAdapter.add(btd.getName() + "\t" + btd.getAddress() + "\n");

               }
           }

    };

    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);




    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.registerReceiver(BTReceiver,filter1);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        BlueAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        this.unregisterReceiver(BTReceiver);
        Toast.makeText(SearchBTDevice.this, "Discovery Stopped!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_btdevice);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);




       searchBTDevices();


    }


    public void searchBTDevices()
    {
        if(!BlueAdapter.startDiscovery())
            Toast.makeText(SearchBTDevice.this, "Failed to Start Discovery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(SearchBTDevice.this, "Discovery Startred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        devicesFound = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.searchpagelistView);
        devicesFound.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);
        devicesFound.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent connectedBTintent = new Intent(SearchBTDevice.this, ConnectedBTDevice.class);
                connectedBTintent.putExtra("BluetoothDevice", btd);
                startActivity(connectedBTintent);

            }
        });

    }


}
```

This is my ***Updated*** **ConnectBTDevice.java** that attempts to make establish the RFCOMM channel. But this is where my app crashes.

```
    package vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ConnectedBTDevice extends AppCompatActivity {

    public BluetoothDevice btd;
    public BluetoothSocket btSocket, tempSocket;
    private UUID myUUID;
    ArrayAdapter arr;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connected_btdevice);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);


        arr  = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);

        btd = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BluetoothDevice");

        connectBT();
        displayStuff();

    }

    public void connectBT() {
        Thread myThread = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                tempSocket = null;

                try {
                    tempSocket = btd.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();

                try {
                    btSocket.connect();
                    arr.add("CONNECTED TO-->" + btd.getName());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    try {
                        btSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        myThread.start();
    }




    public void displayStuff()
    {
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.connectedBTlistView);
        lv.setAdapter(arr);
    }

}
```

This is what my ***Updated*** **logcat** shows

```
03-22 01:40:47.116 28214-11199/vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11810
                                                                                Process: vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert, PID: 28214
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert.ConnectedBTDevice$1.run(ConnectedBTDevice.java:61)
```

Comment: can you please show your connectedactivity.java

Comment: @Calvin It's already given. Look at **ConnectedBTDevice.java**

Answer (score 0):

The exception in logcat is telling you what the issue is.  You are attempting to invoke `BluetoothSocket.connect()` on a null object reference.

You are calling `btSocket.connect()` but btSocket has never been initialized and so it is null.

Either call `tempSocket.connect()` or assign `tempSocket` to `btSocket` before you `connect()`.